# Terminology for number of topological sorts

Tags: partial-order

Is there a standard terminology for the topological sort count over a partial order? I went with magnitude of a poset rather than dimension as this is too close to linear algebra terminology. I wonder if there is a generally accepted choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Number of linear extensions" is probably the most popular one.

Google scholar returned 1000+ matches for `"number of linear extensions"` while `"number of topological order"` or `"number of topological sort"` return less than 10 matches. `"magnitude of a poset"` has only one match with seemingly different meaning.